# how to add my business location to HERE platform?

Tags: location, here-api, websphere-portal

I am trying to add my business location in HERE's platform in order to locate my business when searching for it while ordering online.

Comment: if you mean adding it officially to the HERE map content for public use ? Then use https://mapcreator.here.com/ to get your data added.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your business location at [mapcreator.here.com](https://mapcreator.here.com/). Map Creator offers the ability to edit Points of Interest (POIs), also called Places. There are almost 400 Places categories and 90+ editable attributes.

Just sign in and search for desired location, right click to add a new place, select the relative categories/attributes and save.

More help on how to add and configure places on HERE Map is available at https://mapcreator.here.com/2023.03.01/help/places-and-place-structure.html